# How can i tell if an draggable element is dropped on another draggable element, with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-draggable

I'm using Jquery "draggagle" & "droppable".
When i drop an draggable element on another draggable element i'd like to change the background-color of the element in the bottom. (Not the dropzone)

Some kind of "mouseover", but "elementover" :)

What have i tried?
Barely nothing, i'm trying to figure out what syntax to use.
There is a "over" function for "droppable" but it only works on "dropzones".
 Jquery has a "hover.()" function, but it works for the mouse, i'd like it to be when hovering with another element..
Is this possible?

**UPDATE**

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/0apuqnxd/27/

```
$('.elementsDiv').droppable({
  over: function(){
    $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
  },
  out: function(){
    $(this).css('background-color', '');
  }
});
```

I'm starting to get close, now my problem is that is that if another element is crossing by, the color changes back when "out".

Comment: [jquery droppable](https://jqueryui.com/droppable/#accepted-elements) has this functionality out of the box (`hoverClass` property). You need to use both `.draggable` and `.droppable` plugins

Comment: @RaraituL But i cannot make my `.draggable` element's also `.droppable`. Because when i drop an element it is appended to that "dropzone". This means that i will have alot of dropzones?!

Comment: You want the color to change on drop? in that case you can use `drop` method?

Comment: @SandeepNayak I like to change the color of a draggable element to change, if it's dropped on another draggable element. (Not droppable element)

Answer (score -1):

if its ok with you to use another javascript library

try this one

go down to "Drag and drop" sample you will find the code to what you want.

http://interactjs.io/

Comment: Thank you. I will look into this!

Comment: I cannot see how this framework should be better than Jquery?

Comment: I did not say that its better or worst than jQuery. what I said that the code in "Drag and Drop" section might help you solving your problem, since it has many color changes in the areas.

Comment: ok, But it still doesn't solve my problem?! Jauery has a "over" and it works just like this. But thats not what i want. I´d like a function that tells me if i drop an element on another draggable element.. i cannot see that on the link you gave me?